# Silverlight: After adding table no datacontext classes are available for the new DomainService class

Tags: linq-to-sql, silverlight-4.0

I'm using a Silverlight 4 WCF RIA Services demo application that uses LinqToSql, that works well.

1. I add a new database table, move the new table to the LinqToSql designer and build the project
2. I add a new DomainService class

I get a dialog with the only option to create an empty DomainService and no DataContext classes are available.

What am I missed?

Thanks in advance

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

For generation domainservice for LinqToSql we have to install the WCF RIA Service Toolkit.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c4f02797-5f9e-4acf-a7dc-c5ded53960a6&displaylang=en

Thanks

Gabriel